# How to Show Push Notification on Android in Flutter?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, push-notification

We are finalising an App in Flutter that uses Firebase messaging. Notifications are arriving on iOS and Android. On iOS, the notification is presented on iOS notification list. But, no notification is showing on Android's notifications list or Android's top bar. I need some help on this. Thanks!

Comment: Without knowing what code or implementation you have done, we can't help!

Comment: https://medium.com/flutterpub/enabling-firebase-cloud-messaging-push-notifications-with-flutter-39b08f2ed723 try this

Comment: i think you might need to specify a notification channel for the Android Notifications